# Is there an adverb that means "according to my knowledge" or "if I remember correctly"?

Tags: single-word-requests, adverbs

I find it useful to give such a disclaimer when stating something from memory or personal knowledge but which I would not guarantee to be correct.

However, saying, e.g., "according to my knowledge" or "if I remember correctly" is also wordy and can be distracting.

There must be a one-word adverb that has a similar meaning or connotation (to one or both of these prhases), and I would appreciate if you could point it out.

I tried looking up 'recallingly' [which would be somewhat analogous to 'allegedly'], but it seems the word does not exist.

Edit: Of course, one could say 'perhaps' or 'maybe', but that has a somewhat different meaning because one could say 'perhaps' or 'maybe' without having any personal knowledge or memory of the thing in question. I would like to convey that I am not merely speculating or opining in the moment but that I have processed the information and now am passing it on to others as I have it in my mind.

Comment: ***Maybe*** you should show us your research. ***Perhaps*** the thesaurus has items you’ve discarded. But seriously, this must ***needs*** a verb not an adverb.

Comment: You could try to revive *"methinks."* But, I ween, you'll not find that e'en in Gothick prose. If, *ut opinor,* you use the Latin, which could be found in science books into the 18th Century, you'd probably have to add "as Cicero says," or some such.  Sorry, not very realistic.

Comment: There is the abbreviation ***iirc*** which might serve you well in an informal situation.

Comment: *To my knowledge*, there is no such adverb as *putatatively* for personal recollection.   But even *putatively* should show that an adverbial form might be a stretch.

Comment: AFAIK, we had to invent an initialism only because there was a void.

Comment: *"There must be a one-word adverb..."* You have a touching, but ingenou, faith in English. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could say **As I recall**

That should do it

Answer (score -1):

probably (adv.)

> **2.** As a sentence adverb qualifying a whole statement: almost certainly;
> **as far as one knows** or can tell; in all probability; most likely. (Now the ordinary use.)
>
> *Probably both causes operate to account for the failure to perceive the difference.*  OED

Comment: I won't add a second downvote, but 'if I remember correctly' may correspond to only an estimated 30% probabliity. And the hedge 'probably' will usually be added based on analysis of data rather than a consideration of the limitations of one's memory.